# CSS form input submit button incorrect height?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a simple form, I can't get the submit button the same height as the text boxes. When I add height to the submit button, it shifts the entire form down. What am I missing?

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/7zknq/1/

```
<style type="text/css"> ::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #acacac; } input { margin: 0; }</style>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<form style="padding:0; margin:0;">
<div style="font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; color:#848484; line-height:36px;">
 Testing a form, padding is off on submit button! 
 <input style="display:inline; background-color:#CCC; border:none; height:36px; width:146px; padding-bottom:3px;" type="text" name="name" />
 <input style="display:inline; background-color:#CCC; border:none; height:36px; width:146px; padding-bottom:3px;" type="text" name="name" />
 <input style="display:inline; background-image:none; background-color:#30aa13; border:none; color:#fff; height:36px; font-size:16px;" value="GO" type="submit" />
</div> 
</form>
```

Thanks in advance, Bob :)

Comment: give `input { line-height: ...}` via css, input elements are display:inline-block or inline so you can change the behavior

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/uNRkm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work.

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style>
body {padding:0px; margin:0px;}
form {
    padding:0px 1px 2px 7px; 
    margin:2px 0px 2px 0px;
    border-bottom:#CCC dotted 1px;
}
form div {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color:#848484;
    line-height:36px;
    display:inline;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #acacac; }
input {
    margin:0px 1px;
    padding:0px;
    border:none;
    background-color:#CCC;
    height:36px;
    width:137px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    font-size:16px;
}
input[type=submit]{
    background:#30aa13;
    color:#fff;
    width: inherit;
    padding:0px 7px;
}
</style>
<form action="javascript:return false;">
    <div>form which is not in form, makes fun!</div>
    <div style="float:right">
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <input type="text" name="name2" />
        <input value="GO" type="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7zknq/43/

[image: screenshot from jsfiddle with firefox]

Comment: line-height is not needed, skusi, your padding only for text input was the problem! :)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to create this. I wanted the form on the same line as the text though, and when I use your code and add float:left or display inline to the form, it still displays below the text. Also, in FF the Go button still shows up 1px above the text fields.

Comment: in Firefox this needs `+"input {vertical-align:bottom;}"

Comment: well i checked now, seems to work.. will check float also, yes it must positioned under, because i added a `<br>`

Comment: I'm stumped, this isn't working. I can't believe I can't get this lining up right, I've only done it a thousand times before.

Comment: this question is simple but still very important and interesting, we get this to work. :)

Comment: well I don't want the whole form floating right, but taking out the <br> was all I needed. I also wanted to add a dotted line to the bottom of the form, but was trying to add padding, thus the original 3px on the inputs: http://jsfiddle.net/7zknq/38/. Maybe I would need a seperate div for the border... hmm.

Answer (score 0):

Add to the button:

```
box-sizing: content-box;
```

Remove from inputs the extra `padding-bottom: 3px`

The input and button have different inherited box-sizing.

http://jsfiddle.net/PY7nn/5/

Comment: button is larger than input with this.

Comment: Works fine from Chrome. For other browsers vendor prefixes may apply. I am dealing with the core of the problem. The button and input have no commune box model.

Comment: well buttons are supposed to have text in the middle (of hight), which conflicts with the idea that text is positioned at baseline. specially on inline-block or inline elements this makes trouble, if padding is not set, otherwise the normal padding is inherited from the dom model of buttons. buttons can use the full box-model space, so the text will never overlapp there borders. but exactly this is possible with text. so it can't have the same boxmodel. so a given padding is needed to override this difference

Comment: Thank you, but it does not display correctly in Firefox or IE. I don't really know what you mean by vendor prefixes may apply. Which ones, could you elaborate? And also, why is it that Firefox and Chrome display differently now, when before I never had a problem making both of them look the same (it was only ever IE that gave me headaches)?

Comment: padding: 0px 10px; for all input elements, even input[type=submit], and a given hight to have a relation where padding can depend on.

Comment: why 10px for padding spefically? I don't want padding on the input button (I want the button small, which is why it only has the text GO).

Comment: Made it work in Firefox. I do not belive that there is need for hacks when this can be resolved with a reset. http://jsfiddle.net/PY7nn/5/ Works in Chrome and FF. Did not checked in IE

Comment: @user2238812 vendor prefixes are -moz, -webkit, -o, -ms. That is what you needed to apply to make it work in other browsers.

Comment: @user2238812 you could set padding also 0px at all for the text-inputs: http://jsfiddle.net/7zknq/42/